# Draw all connected graphs of order $5$ in which the distance between every two distinct vertices is odd.

Tags: graph-theory

I'm working in the following graph theory excercise:

> Draw all connected graphs of order $5$ in which the distance between every two distinct vertices is odd. Explain why you know that you have drawn all such graphs.

Is there another graph different to the complete graph of order $5$? Thanks in advance for any hint or help.

Comment: The complete graph of order $5$ (every vertex is connected to every other vertex) is one such graph because the distance between any two vertices is $1$.

Comment: You need to specify simple graphs or there are an infinite number.  You can have any number of edges joining a pair of vertices.

Comment: Also does it include directed or only undirected graphs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** If $d(u_0,v)=n\gt0$ then $u_0$ has a neighbor $u_1$ such that $d(u_1,v)=n-1$.

Comment: @Servaes Yep. Revised and undeleted. Hope I got it right now!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for points abcde without loss of generality ab are connected. wlog bc are connected. The current distance between a and c is 2 this can only be made odd by connecting ac. Next step wlog cd are connected...